# Why _beginthread return error ENOMEM

Tags: c++, stress-testing

I have a server that implemented in C++ running on a Windows 2003 enterprise with 25GB RAM.

During a stress test, I see when it is trying to create a new thread by calling _beginthread, I got ENOMEM which means "Not enough memory".

But I don't understand why it is out of memory, perfmon data shows that at that time, the process has used 1.2GB VM and similar physical memory, there are only 250 threads.

Can anyone help me to analyse or explain why I still got this error?

Comment: Is this a 32-bit application? If so, it's limited to 2GB total (physical + virtual) memory, and you say "used 1.2GB VM and similar physical memory"), which would exceed 2GB.

Comment: How many threads it makes ?! You have a upper bound for number of threads you make. Do you use a thread pool ?!

Comment: @KenWhite Why you said limit to 2GB(physical + virtual)? I think 2GB is the virtual limit. For physical memory, I have PAE enabled, so it is more than 4G.

Comment: @KamranAmini at that time it is 250 threads, I know that 32bit application can create 2024 threads, so it is more than enough.

Comment: @performanceuser: No. It's 2GB total **address space**, which includes both VM and physical memory. (Unless PAE is enabled, and the executable header has the LARGE_MEMORY_AWARE flag set, in which case it can be extended to 3GB.)

Comment: You might be able to create 2024 threads under some conditions, but keep in mind that each thread has a stack, and if you pass 0 for the size of that stack to _beginthread then it uses the parent process stack size.  I believe the default is 1 megabyte, so you can see it could add up pretty quickly.

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks a lot for mentioning that, but I still don't understand why it is VM + physical memory, can you explain more or direct me to some pages that explains this?

Comment: @KenWhite Please refer to this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366912%28v=VS.85%29.aspx I don't think you theory about 2GB limit is correct.

Comment: @RetiredNinja You theory cannot explain why I see the error. My server is far from the limit based on the numbers.

Comment: IIRC, it has to do with 32-bit pointers on Windows being signed integers, and the OS reserving 2GB for itself starting at the 4GB address and proceeding down. You're misreading the link you provided: "The virtual address space for 32-bit Windows is 4 gigabytes (GB) in size and divided into two partitions: one for use by the process and the other reserved for use by the system." means that the **process** (application) gets 2GB and the **system** (Windows) gets the other 2GB.

Comment: @KenWhite That 2GB is virtual memory NOT physical memory. I have never learnt or seen anywhere mentioning there is a limit for VM + physical memory

Comment: @KenWhite This page shows physical memory limit: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Research it yourself, then. I'm not going to debate it in comments. I've only been programming for Windows 32 since the day Win95 was released, and still earn my money every day doing so. :-) What do I know?

Comment: @KenWhite I would be really appreciated if you can direct me to some pages that explain your theory. I have done a lot of research, but never seen anywhere says 2GB is VM + physical

Comment: Again, you're reading the link wrong. The last page says `2GB for user mode processes` (meaning your application) and `2GB kernel mode space` (Windows itself) in rows 1 and 3 of the table, and row 1 mentions that user mode can be extended to 3GB with the `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE` flag set in the header. 2GB user space is all your app gets (3GB with the flag). That's it (both physical and virtual together are the address space). I don't care how hard you argue; it's a fact. You provided two links yourself that both say so, right from Microsoft.

Comment: @KenWhite Can you explain why the title of the page is "Virtual Address Space" ?

Comment: @KenWhite Also if the limit is VM + physical, why Microsoft provides two pages to define two different limits?

Comment: Because not all of it has to be physical. You can have 1GB physical RAM installed in your machine, and your app can still allocate up to 2GB. (Most of it would be virtual, and your app would spend most of it's time being paged in and out.) I'm through here; I keep explaining, and you keep debating everything. This isn't a chat room or discussion site, and all of this back and forth isn't appropriate here. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite I agree with your last comments, 1GB RAM can support 2GB VM. But it has nothing to do with what we are debating. Just to borrow your example, there is a machine with 1GB RAM, and there is a 32bit process allocated 1.7GB VM, does it mean this process can only have 0.3GB RAM(you said VM + RAM limit is 2GB)? I am fine if you don't want to continue with this debating. I just don't think this is cause of the issue I am seeing.

Comment: For the last time: **Each process** gets 2GB of address space (both virtual and physical memory). If you have a machine with 1GB of RAM installed and a 32-bit app running that has allocated 1.7GB, **that application** can only allocate another 0.3GB. **Another application** can start, and it also has 2GB of virtual address space available. **Each process has it's own 2GB of virtual address space**. A process can be though of as an application; every thread it launches is part of the parent process.

Comment: @KenWhite I totally understand and agree you last sentence: Each process separately has 2GB of virtual address space. But maybe your first comment is confusing. Both VM and RAM limit is 2GB, you said 2GB(VM + RAM). Now I agree with you, but how can this be the cause of the issue?

Comment: It's **total address space** period. Not separate VM and PM. **Total** address space. 1.2GB VM + about the same is more than 2GB. What part of that do you not understand? I really am through here; I could have helped half a dozen other people in the time I've spend here repeating myself to you when you won't listen. Windows is telling you (`ENOMEM`), the two links you provided yourself told you, and I've explained it several times. Good luck - hope you get it figured out.

Comment: What I don't understand is why a process cannot have 1.2GB VM AND 1GB PM. Are you saying when a process has 1.2GB VM can only have 0.8GB PM?

Comment: What is **hard to understand**?? You have 2GB memory (total - PM and VM). If you use 1.2GB (total, whether it's VM, PM, or both combined), you have 0.8GB left (total, whether it's VM, PM, or both). **2GB - (total used) = total left**. It's simple, basic math.

Comment: @KenWhite VM is virtual memory. It is just a concept in the OS, if you learnt OS, it is just several array tables to map the virtual memory address to physical memory address. All the information are stored in PM, So if a process allocated 1G of VM, this 1G of VM must have been mapped to somewhere in the physical memory. Why you keep combining VM and PM together?

Comment: I give up (again). We're talking **address space**. Your 32-bit process gets 2GB total **address space**, which is made up of both VM and PM. The limit is on **TOTAL ADDRESS SPACE**, which is combined VM and PM. **PLEASE** actually **read the words**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up because of a memory leak in our application.

Answer (score 2):

A thread typically requires 1 MB of **unfragmented** address space. If your stress test has fragmented memory to the point where no 1 MB stretches are available, you wouldn't be able to create any new threads. This can be achieved by as little as 2000 allocations of one byte each, in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

A typical 32-bit application would run out of (virtual) memory after creating a bit less than 2048 threads. By default every thread reserves 1MB of contiguous virtual address space, so that 2048 threads would need 2GB of virtual memory. This is the maximum a 32-bit process may consume in user mode.

P.S. There's an option (at least on Windows) to configure OS to reserve up to 3GB of virtual address space in the user-mode.

Comment: But I am only using 250 threads, and my VM usage is 1.2G. Based on your answer, it looks like I should not see the error, is it?

Comment: While this is technically correct (the default 1MB stack), it has nothing to do with this problem; you've misread. The question says **two hundred fifty** threads, not **two thousand five hundred**.